# Sum of two vectors is the vector that has components equal to sum of components

Tags: algebra-precalculus, euclidean-geometry

Consider geometric vectors for example, where the addition is defined by parallelogram law. How can I prove that Sum of two vectors is the vector that has components equal to sum of components of individual vectors with respect to some basis? In fact, how can I do the same for any vector space where the addition defined is consistent with the defintion of vector space but having a non obvious formulation such as parallelogram law?

Comment: How does the parallelogram rule define the sum of vectors? Surely you need to prove that adding two vectors forms a parallelogram to prove that addition of vectors (defined as “translate the second vector until it starts where the first ends”) is commutative?

Comment: Let us say that the sum of two vectors is given by the diagonal formed by the two vectors. Then the definition satisfies all properties of vector space. But how can you guarantee that Sum of two vectors is the vector that has components equal to sum of components with respect to some basis?

Answer (score 1):

Let $v,\,w$ be vectors, and write $v=\sum_i (v\cdot e_i)e_i$ etc. for basis elements $e_i$ so $$v+w=\sum_i ((v+w)\cdot e_i)e_i=\sum_i (v\cdot e_i+w\cdot e_i)e_i=\sum_i (v\cdot e_i)e_i+\sum_i (w\cdot e_i)e_i.$$The $i$th component of the first and last expression are $e_i$ coefficients, respectively $(v+w)_i$ and $v_i+w_i$.

Edit: we can do without dot products as long as the components $v_i$ satisfy $v=\sum_i v_i e_i$ for some linearly independent basis elements $e_i$ so the $v_i$ in that sum are unique. Then $$\sum_i (v+w)_ie_i=v+w=\sum_i v_ie_i+\sum_i w_i e_i=\sum_i (v_i+w_i)e_i\implies (v+w)_i=v_i+w_i.$$

Comment: Can you do the same for any arbitrary definition of addition for any vector space given that it is consistent with vector space definition?

Comment: @Akhil If you're asking me to prove components add, components will have to exist. If they do, we're in the above situation. Just about the only generalisation we're allowed is to change the identity from $\sum_i e_i e_i^T$ to $\sum_{ij} g_{ij} e_i e_j^T$, which just means something other than an orthonormal basis has been chosen. The proof it still works then is an exercise.

Comment: Is there a more fundamental proof that doesn't involve dot product?

Comment: @Akhil See my edit.

Comment: But the meaning of addition changes in the step v+w = ∑vi ei + ∑wi ei = ∑(vi+wi) ei. It changes from the one we defined to the one that adds the components, whose validity is what I'm asking you to prove.

Comment: @Akhil What are you talking about? In that line the first $=$ (which you've edited out) defines $(v+w)_i$, the second uses the definitions of the $v_i$ and $w_i$, the third is just algebra since by definition vector addition respects scalars that way, and we're done.

Comment: Suppose V, W are geometric vectors, then V + W means addition by parallelogram law where as the next addition symbols means algebraic addition of components. What I'm asking is how can you prove that parallelogram rule is equivalent to algebraic addition of components?

Answer (score 0):

What does the vector $(1,2)$ mean? Well it means the sum of 1 times the first basis vector (say $i$) and 2 times the second (say $j$). So e.g. you want to prove that:
$$(a,b)+(c,d)= (a i + b j) + (c i + d j) = (a + c) i + (b + d) j = (a+c, b+d).$$

So you need to prove that vector addition is commutative, associative, and that scalar multiplication distributes over (vector) addition.

Then everything should fall out.